# Heartbeating to cloudera manager fails

Tags: cloudera-manager

During parcel distribution, I found that my node is not making progress. Looking at the logs, this it what he is complaining about:

```
[18/Jun/2015 11:16:22 +0000] 16658 MainThread agent        ERROR    Heartbeating to master.adastragrp.com:7182 failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py", line 980, in send_heartbeat
    response = self.requestor.request('heartbeat', dict(request=heartbeat))
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/ipc.py", line 139, in request
    return self.issue_request(call_request, message_name, request_datum)
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/ipc.py", line 255, in issue_request
    return self.read_call_response(message_name, buffer_decoder)
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/ipc.py", line 235, in read_call_response
    raise self.read_error(writers_schema, readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/ipc.py", line 244, in read_error
    return AvroRemoteException(datum_reader.read(decoder))
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 444, in read
    return self.read_data(self.writers_schema, self.readers_schema, decoder)
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 448, in read_data
    if not DatumReader.match_schemas(writers_schema, readers_schema):
  File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/io.py", line 379, in match_schemas
    w_type = writers_schema.type
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Note that this node is on the same machine as the cloudera manager. No firewall is running. The WebUI shows that the agent is actually sending heartbeats every few seconds. What is going wrong here?